# Grails (v2.2) app starts via run-app, but dies when deploying the war on tomcat 7

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails

I have a grails 2.2 app that runs fine when I do a clean checkout from svn and do grails run-app.
(I've already blown away my .grails/2.2.0 and .grails/ivy-cache directories and re-downloaded the dependencies)

However, when I create the war (grails war) and deploy it in tomcat7, it dies with the following error:

> 2013-03-08 04:12:17,096 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)

I have the following plugins:

- drools-gorm v0.5.6
- joda-time v1.4
- mail v1.0.1

Any suggestions?

Comment: Turns out to be an open issue with drools-gorm.  There's an open jira issue for it at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDROOLSGORM-8?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: This is related to dataSource. Please verify that you have put the right credentials for prod mode.

Comment: It's the drools-gorm plugin,  it works fine w/o that plugin (things persist to the db etc)

Answer (score 0):

Problems with the initialization of the `transactionManagerPostProcessor` bean are often issues with the `dataSource`.

Running `grails run-app` uses the `development` environment.  Running `grails war` uses the `production` environment by default, so the problem may be the production `dataSource` configuration.  If you want to build a warfile that uses the development mode settings, run `grails -Dgrails.env=development war`.

Comment: there are no differences in datasource between production and war - I'll try it shortly.  I have just finished removing the drools-gorm plugin, rebuilt the war and it deployed and ran fine though.  So I think I've narrowed it down to that plugin causing it.

Comment: Ok, looks like its that plugin - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDROOLSGORM-8?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel